# Dispatching actions before rendering component

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm using redux and es6. I want to dispatch an action before components will mount. The problem is that with redux newest syntaxis componentWillMount doesn't exists any more. So... where should i dispatch this action.

My case: I have a component that needs user's info (such as name, for example). I need to get the user's name before that component mounts.

thanks,

Comment: componentWillMount is from ReactJS, and dispatching actions is from redux. You should read this documentation on how to use Redux with ReactJS : http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: yeah, ok, but you understood my question, and still didn't answer it. What i need is a middleware ;) @hugohowchoong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your component to a field in your state, let's call it "name". When the component renders, make sure it checks if name is not empty; if it is then it renders it, if not then it renders nothing.

In the componentDidMount, fire your dispatch as normal - this in turn will reduce and end up changing the value of "name" in your state. This will cause a re-render and will then show properly.

componentWillMount only exists server side, so it is usually not the best idea to dispatch actions from it, as if you just had your client side code, they wouldn't work.